# Why is my comparison to null, of a value contained in a System.Data.DataRow object, failing?

Tags: .net, database, null, system.data

I am converting an app's database from Access to MS SQL Server and encountered a problem with a line of code that checks to see if an item retrieved from the database is null.

It essentially looks like this:

```
if (System.Data.DataRow["foo"] == null)
{
    //do something
}
```

I know the value in column "foo" is null, but the check fails.  It works against an Access database, but not MS SQL Server.  I can see why.  The call is returning "{}" instead of null.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking against `DbNull.Value` instead of `null`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (System.Data.DataRow["foo"].IsDBNull)
```